# Ajax xmlhttp.onreadystatechange function

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this code:

```
function loadRegions()
{
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
         xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
         xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
           alert("Ready:"+xmlhttp.status);
           xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
           x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("region");
           alert(x[0]);
           alert(x[1]);
       }
   }

   var ctrcode = frm.elements['countrycode'];
   xmlhttp.open("GET","http://mydomain.gr/regionslist.php?countrycode="+ctrcode.value,true);
   xmlhttp.send();
}
```

I have a `select` item in my HTML and when someone selects an item then this function is called to get the regions of this country. I can see from my console that the request is done, but the response is never gotten. My `onreadystatechange` function is never called. When I delete `xmlhttp.status==200` then the function is called but the `xmlDoc` object is `null` and `xmlhttp.status==0`. The URL I use works if I call it alone. Why does my `onreadystatechange` function not work and why does it not return status 200?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this line before calling send() function:

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

and also set onReadyStateChange function after calling open()

reasons:
1) The responseXML property represents the XML response when the complete HTTP response has been received (when readyState is 4), when the Content-Type header specifies the MIME (media) type as text/xml, application/xml, or ends in +xml. If the Content-Type header does not contain one of these media types, the responseXML value is null.
2) After the initial response, all event listeners will be cleared. Call open() before setting an onreadystatechange listener. 
here is references of the [first](http://www.oxymoronical.com/experiments/apidocs/interface/nsIXMLHttpRequest) and the [second](http://www.devx.com/webdev/Article/33024/1954) reason

Comment: reasons:
1) The responseXML property represents the XML response when the complete HTTP response has been received (when readyState is 4), when the Content-Type header specifies the MIME (media) type as text/xml, application/xml, or ends in +xml. If the Content-Type header does not contain one of these media types, the responseXML value is null.
2) After the initial response, all event listeners will be cleared.
 Call open() before setting an onreadystatechange listener.

Comment: here is references of [the first](http://www.oxymoronical.com/experiments/apidocs/interface/nsIXMLHttpRequest) and [the second](http://www.devx.com/webdev/Article/33024/1954) reason

Comment: It looks like your two comments are better suited to be edits to your answer. That will put all of the information in one place, allow for further edits, and allow for more accurate voting and answer acceptance. Other users will see all of the information in your answer, which is what is considered during voting.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your response but the result is the same.I turned my code as you suggested but i keep getting the same results.

Comment: I uploaded on a server and stop using it localy and all work perfect.Do you have any idea why does that happen.